# Question about Accept Rate

Tags: support, accept-rate

My Answer Accept rate is 88%.

I would really like this to be 100%. So I went and deleted some old posts that had no answers for the last month. I think there were 5 of them. Surely this should at least raise my Acceptance Rate a little?

Any ideas why it stayed the same, and what can I do to get my acceptance rate to 100%?

Comment: "deleted some old posts that had no answers for the last month"---what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: Cool. Did you get a tumbleweed for that?

Comment: Why didn't you just update the questions in the hope that maybe there would be a different set of eyes that might have solved your problem?

Comment: The questions I deleted were because I realised they were possible duplicates, or would just get flamed down.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You do not need to have a rate of 100% (88% is pretty darn good btw). Don't take this too seriously! Be careful what you delete, it could be valuable to others even if you don't think so! Even if it is an unanswered question.

Answer (score 27):

The calculation is explained [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/).

> The following rules are used in the calculation:
>
> - Questions must not be community wiki.
> - Questions must not be closed.
> - Questions must be more than 3 days old.
> - **Questions must have at least 1 answer.**
> - There must be at least four eligible questions as determined by the above rules, otherwise the statistic will not appear.

Therefore it doesn't help to delete posts without answers.

Answer (score 14):

[It's heavily cached](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/#comment-32274). Takes a while to update the value.

Answer (score 2):

I understand that a question must at least have 1 answer to be taken into account when calculating the accept rate. But what if I answered my own question? I can't accept my answer as the correct one but my accept rate will still count the question as "answered but no answer accepted".

Also what happens if a bounty ran out and I realize that a given answer was the best one - I don't seem to be able to accept an answer afterwards any more.

Comment: You can accept your own answer, just wait a couple of days.

Comment: mmmh ... should 6 weeks be enough ? ;)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160855/dijit-form-select-will-close-surrounding-tooltip-dialog-in-ie