# Getting "rid" of a question

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, accept-rate

I have already asked about withdrawing a question before : it was no longer relevant to me. I was told that once the question was asked, it was no longer mine. It belonged to the community. And I liked the concept.

And I have another question that I feel will stay unresolved, as the few answers don't satisfy me.

But I wanted to have a 100% acceptance rate: I hate hanging unanswered questions.

If I turn the question into a community question, will it still need to have an accepted answer? Will it count toward my acceptance rate? Will it show in my profile as an unanswered question?

Can I do something else about it? I feel like accepting an incomplete answer is useless or worse.

I'm thinking about my last question and I know it hasn't been up for long but it could be any other question as well.

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18033/question-about-accept-rate

Comment: Read again. I don't want to delete the question. I want to get rid of it. It can belong to the community, I just don't anything to do with it anymore.

Comment: If you read the answers of the dupe, you will see that CW questions do not count to the accept rate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to "own" a question anymore, making it community wiki is the way to go.  The question will no longer count against your accept rate, but it will still show up in your profile.

I'd prefer the CW option over accepting an incomplete or otherwise unsatisfactory answer any day.

Comment: How to get rid of a question and prevent showing it in profile then? ;)

Comment: @Mehrdad: I wish there was a way.  I still have the "Jon Skeet Facts" stub at the top of my questions list.  I'll never ask a more popular question than that, so I'm afraid I'm stuck with it forever.

Comment: Change the ordering system from "votes" to something else :P

Comment: @Silence: That was worth a try, but it defaults back to "votes" when I reload the page. :(

Comment: I will light a candle for poor little Billy. ...and open a new thread.

Answer (score 2):

If you are unsatisfied with the answers you have received, you always have the option of answering your own question.  You also have the opportunity to accept your own answer, if you think it is best ;).  You will have to wait for a couple days after the initial question was posted to accept your own.

Comment: Already done that on another question. But this time, I have no answer that will satisfy other readers seeking answers. So I can't use the "accept my own answer" option.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is really crappy/useless, you can flag it for a moderator to delete it. I have done that with a question regarding small-scale DVD production that was really useless and received useless answers.

Comment: The question is not useless. It's simply about a very little known technology. I have seen this many times on SO : questions about obscure technology or library with no answers.

Comment: There may be value to others in your question, even if there is no value to you. The fact that there were no good answers is valuable as the person looking for an answer can see what doesn't work.