# Is the accepted answer rate a batch job?

Tags: support, reputation, accept-rate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question about Accept Rate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18033/question-about-accept-rate)

When is the accepted answer rate updated?

I thought it would be real time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the exact time, but according to [this blog comment](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/#comment-32274), it is not real time, it could take up to a few hours.

> the value is cached heavily so expect any change to take hours to
> appear (depends on traffic)