# How often is a users accept rate recalculated?

Tags: support

I've accepted answers in 18 of the 20 questions I've posted to SO; but my rate is stuck at 82%, not 90%.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/85661/dan-neely

Is this an infrequently run batch process or has something caused it to stop running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's updated periodically.  No need to worry.

**Update**:  Actually, I just looked and it seems you have 21 questions.  2 don't have any answers so they don't count.  2 aren't old enough so they don't count either.  That leaves us with 17 eligible questions.  Of those all but three have accepted answers.  That works out to 14/17 or 82%, so I guess you are stuck until you you accept an answer on one of these:

[Why is my application using CSC during execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705427/why-is-my-application-using-csc-during-execution)
[Show controls on multiple pages of a tab control in the designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708615/show-controls-on-multiple-pages-of-a-tab-control-in-the-designer)
[Inno Setup uninstall executable location and name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631789/inno-setup-uninstall-executable-location-and-name)

Answer (score 2):

Please see: [Question about Accept Rate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18033/question-about-accept-rate)

And on the blog, it it mentioned by Jeff that the accept rate is a heavily cached feature, so it will take some time to change if you have made recent changes.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/#comment-32274