# Accept rate bug?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, accept-rate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question about Accept Rate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18033/question-about-accept-rate)

How comes this [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/181018/saurabh) has an accept rate of 0% despite having accepted at least one [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220366/get-unicode-value-of-a-character/2220476#2220476) out of 6?

Comment: It takes time to calculate that accept rate. Just give it a day. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18033/question-about-accept-rate/

Comment: one day is not enough, question must be 3 days old...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was accepted at sometime between a few hours ago and now.

The acceptance rate is not "live" information, it's calculated by a batch job every few hours.

Comment: Damn! I've passed my SO reputation on Meta. This is a sad day.

Comment: Welcome to the club. What do you drink?

Comment: @random: I guess I'll have to drown myself with beer now. And it's only Monday.

Comment: Drunk on a Monday? Questionably good way to end the week then!

Comment: It's always drunk in Iceland... wait, how did that go again?

Comment: @gnostradamus: *I'm* always drunk in Iceland.

Comment: Seems like people is trying to convince me of moving to Iceland. You had me at Ice.