# When is the Accept Rate updated after deleting a question?

Tags: discussion, support

First of all, i did read through [Question about accept rate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18033/question-about-accept-rate). But reading through few posts, was not clear, So posting this question.

My SO accept rate was 88%, I went to my questions tab and looked up for the question because of which it was 88% and not 100%. (it was marked in some red comment).

I reviewed the question and answer again, that question in itself was not constructive. So rather than accepting the answer I deleted the question.

But my accept rate was not updated to 100. Its been like 7-8 hours since that action. So whats wrong? I mean it should be updated to 100 and will be soon (delay in update) or something else?"

Comment: Obligatory "Don't care so much about your accept rate" comment. Accept answers that solve your problem. If a question doesn't get one, so be it. You may look at the question to see whether you can improve it so that it can get a satisfactory answer, but beyond that, leave it unaccepted.

Comment: I'd chalk it up to caching, and that it would have been gone in 24 hours, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: @AlEverett yes but I was reviewing the question and it was , if i say not constructive. So deleted it. if it would have been useful for the community I would have been at peace with 88%  :D

Comment: @Mukul: Fair enough. My comment was directed more at people who think that an accept rate of 100% is desired and/or necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't recalc accept rates when deleting a question *at this time*, it'll sync up tonight around 00:00 UTC.

Comment: Alright. Thank you :)

Comment: Makes sense, when you think about it.  I've asked 152 questions, so displaying my accept rate in near real-time requires a SQL query to count the number of checkmarks on those 152 questions.  Not exactly a slow query, but not cost-free either, especially if it has to execute every time one of my questions is displayed.